# How to allow Cloud SQL connections to an auto scaling group?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Google Cloud SQL has a firewall feature that lets me input the IPs I allow to connect to cloud SQL. I was wondering, how would I allow access to an autoscaling webserver since I don't know their IPs?

Will enabling cloud sql api permissions on the server allow it to work without adding the IP on the cloud SQL UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sql-proxy) to connect which does not require IP whitelisting.